# Accordion in material design within html table

Tags: angular

A table is been build using html  tag. It has a button in Details Column on click of which details of the product need to be shown as an accordion. Please help this achieve using material design.

This is the html table structure.

```
 <table>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <tr *ngFor = "let row of indexes">
        <td *ngFor = "let id of row>{{id}}</td>
        <td><button>DETAILS</button></td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

Please find the structure in this image[image: This is how it should be]

Comment: Any news? Problem solved or still exists? :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036475/3631348

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <!-- .. your headers -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <!-- wrap that template-element around your row(s) -->
     <template ngFor let-company [ngForOf]="companies">
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ company.company }}
          </td>
           <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="open(company)">
                {{ company.showDetails ? 'hide' : 'details' }}
             </button>
           </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- .. your details will be shown under that 'data-row' .. -->
        <tr *ngIf="company.showDetails"> <!-- any condition here to show details .. ! -->
         <td>
            .. details .. details .. details ..
         </td>
        </tr>
     </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Minimal repro: https://plnkr.co/edit/2061oMJopjBQW85T9JKL?p=preview